# How to decode a .chm file?

Tags: macos, file-conversion

I'd like to extract content of old `.chm` file into individual html files.

Is there an app or command line tool for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $1 (instead of $18 for FileJuicer) you might consider this app:

### [CHM Decompiler](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chm-decompiler/id476013157)

It worked correctly for me. (I have no relationship with the developer, just a happy customer.)

Answer (score 10):

This is pretty easy to do for free you just have to use Terminal and install Homebrew and chmlib.

1. Open Terminal. (/Applications/Utilities/)
2. Install Homebrew by visiting http://brew.sh/ and follow the installation instructions. Or just copy paste this command into Terminal and run it.

   ```
   /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```
3. After the install is complete type `brew install chmlib` in Terminal and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
4. Move the file you want to extract to your Desktop.
5. Go back to Terminal and type:

   ```
   extract_chmLib ~/Desktop/name_of_the_file.chm ~/Desktop/name_of_the_file
   ```

   Just be sure to replace `name_of_the_file.chm` with the actual name of the file. This will create a new folder on your desktop.
6. Open the folder and double click the file *index.html*. This will open the document in your web browser.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps http://echoone.com/filejuicer/formats/chm will do the job for you.

FWIW, my chm to HTML workflow differs though. I use iCHM app (http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/28171/ichm) for OS X to convert chm to PDF to preserve formatting. After editing it (using Adobe Acrobat) as necessary, only then do I convert to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

[Tubby](http://bluecouch.com/tubby/).

From the website:

> *Tubby is no longer maintained or supported.* It is a CHM file expander,
>   opening Combined HTML Help files and outputting their contents in a
>   folder of the same name. You can access the source on the side and use
>   as you see fit.
>
> Requirements. Tubby runs on Mac OS X 10.3.9 or higher.